# VueJS DOM issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking for a way to make nestable dom elements draggable using VueJS. So far achieved a lot. However, it seems after drag and drop, some elements are disappearing.

Can anyone take a look and guide me what's went wrong?

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-drag">
  <draggable v-model="nodes" :options="{group: { name:'group'}}" class="draggable">
    <template v-for="element in children">
      <element-type :attrs="element"><draggable-nested :children="element.children"/></element-type>
    </template>
  </draggable>
</script>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/minuwan/gc5xjLru/

Comment: You need a [`key`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for Vue to properly correlate data to DOM objects.

Comment: @RoyJ The problem is '<template>' cannot be keyed. :(

Comment: You can put the `key` on the `element`. That still doesn't keep things from disappearing, tho.

Comment: @RoyJ I also tried. I converted the template tag to a div and tried. Still the same.

Comment: The problem looks to be with `draggable-nested`. If you take that out and replace it with `{{element.id}}`, the behavior is fine.

Comment: @RoyJ That's true, But I can't think any other way to recursive the draggable nodes.

Comment: @RoyJ THis is the very basic version of the same. https://jsfiddle.net/minuwan/Lu8bwg5e  Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing the empty tasks array. (and the draggable-nested issue mentioned by Roy)

if you define it for each object, you allow it to be moved in.

---

Updated code snippet for original jsfiddle example

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-drag">
  <draggable :element="'ul'" :list="tasks" class="draggable" :options="{group:{ name:'group'}}">
    <template v-for="el in children" :key="el.name">
      <p>{{el.name}}</p>
            <element-type :attrs="el"><draggable-nested :children="el.children"/></element-type>
    </template>
  </draggable>
</script>
```

Comment: Ah ha... Gotcha... That's it then. But in my complex JSFiddle I do the same and couldn't figure out what's wrong. Can you take a look, please ? 

https://jsfiddle.net/minuwan/gc5xjLru [This is the version without doing what you told].

Comment: I think the issue may be that you're using v-model. I've updated answer to include the code: https://jsfiddle.net/zbythjoa/